# Usage of the word "through"

Tags: word-usage

What is the meaning of the phrase: "The malware affects IE9 through IE11(Internet Explorer)"?  Why can't we use "from IE9 to IE11" instead?

Comment: You can use that instead. The use of *through* in contexts like your example, seems to be part of American English in particular.

Answer (score 1):

It's a difference between US and British English. Brits say "1 to 9" and Americans say "1 through 9" (or frequently "1 thru 9")

Answer (score 1):

Using **through** eliminates the question of whether the final endpoint (IE11) should be included in the range or excluded.  Here IE11 is stated to be affected.

Answer (score 1):

"The malware affects from IE9 to IE11" sounds really strange to me in American English. The only example I can think of where the construct "*verb* ***from*** *x* ***to*** *y*" sounds "correct" when defining an inclusive set would be "awake from dusk to dawn". I don't think most American English speakers or writers would use that instead of "*verb* *x* ***through*** *y*" when they mean to include the *x* and *y* as part of the set.

Saying "The malware affects IE9 through IE11" is more technically accurate to me, since you are unambiguously saying that IE9 is affected, IE11 is affected, and so are all the versions in between. And you get to trim a word from the sentence!

Comment: The construct "_verb from x to y_" also sounds "correct" in the phrase _count from 1 to 10_.

Answer (score -1):

"To" indicates that the stopping point of the iterative count ends before ie11 begins.
"Through" includes ie11 in the count.

That is to say using only integers, and excluding fractions 1 to 10 is the same as 1 through 9.

The easiest way to see the difference is with time. If you work from 1 to 5, you've worked 4 hours, because you stop at 5 without going through it. The five o'clock hour isn't included. If you work from 1 through 5, you're off work at about 6.

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: @ ben When you say, for example, "count from 1 to 5 " 5 is included in the range, you're not going to stop at 4. "to" does not indicate that the stopping point is before the last item in the list.

Comment: I agree with Jo. In some contexts, _to_ is ambiguous whether the endpoint is included or not, but it is not right to say that it always excludes it.

Comment: "to" isn't ambiguous. In counting it expresses the end point is reached in a range. OED. In counting "to" means you stop at X. 1 to 5 definately does not include 5. 1 through 5 includes 5. This is true in both English and Mathematics. http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/to

Comment: @JoBedard we do say count 1 to 5 and then we do use 5 in the count, but that doesn't mean that it's proper. Using "to" in proper English wouldn't include the 5. OP isn't asking about colloquial phrasing, the question is about proper usage of the word.

Comment: @JoBedard The easiest way to see the difference is with time. If you work from 1 to 5, you've worked 4 hours, because you stop at 5 without going through it. The five o'clock hour isn't included. If you work from 1 through 5, you're off work at about 6.

Comment: Do you really expect shops that are open "From Monday to Friday" to close for the weekend on Thursday afternoon?

Comment: No, I know what they mean. But, if they send their wording to a copy-editor I would expect the copy-editor to advise changing the wording to "Monday through Friday". Which is probably why Microsoft used that specific language in their document.

Comment: @Ben If you work from 1 to 5, you get off work around five. It doesn't mean, as you are implying, that you get off at 4:59 because 5:00 is not reached. If you work from 1 through 5… well, then nothing, because _through_, at least in my idiolect, cannot be used for stretches of time at all. But I would certainly _never_ understand it to mean that you get off work at 6. Nor would I ever expect a train from London to Manchester to stop just outside Manchester. _To_ is or can be ambiguous and requires context; _through_ is unambiguous, but cannot be used in all the same contexts that _to_ can.

Comment: I'm not trying to imply anything. I'm saying: going to something is not the same thing as going through something. Going to the Atlantic Ocean is different than going through the Atlantic Ocean. "Making love to someone" is different than "making love through someone". The words "to" and "through" are different. working to 5:00 means stopping at 5:00. Working through the 5:00 hour means going to 5:59:59. I don't know why there's such contention here.

Comment: Ben Plont, it would be helpful if you explain what you mean by "proper English". It has been established in other answers and comments that the use of *through* in contexts like this, is part of American English in particular. It is not used in England and the rest of the UK, which uses *to* instead. That makes it clear that there is not one, absolute rule for this and therefore, there is no single, "proper English". The answer depends on which kind of English a person uses.